# Explicit default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer

This code compiles fine with GCC 5.X, MSVC, but GCC 6.X gives error:

> *"converting to 'a' from initializer list would use explicit
>   constructor 'a::a()'"*, clang *"chosen constructor is explicit in
>   copy-initialization"*.

Removing `explicit` or changing to `a c{}` fixes the problem, but I`m curious why it works this way.

```
class a
{
public:
    explicit a () {}
};
struct b
{
    a c;
};

int main() {
    b d{};
}
```

Comment: use `b d;` or `b d{a{}}` is also work

Answer (score 25):

`b` is an [aggregate](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#1). When you initialize it using an initializer list, the elements in the list will initialize the first *n* members of the aggregate, where *n* is the number of elements in the list. The remaining elements of the aggregate are *copy-list-initialized*.

So in your example, `c` will be *copy-list-initialized*, but that is ill-formed if the chosen constructor is `explicit`, hence the error.

The relevant standard quotes are

*[[dcl.init.aggr]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#3)*

> When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list as specified in [dcl.init.list], the elements of the initializer list are taken as initializers for the elements of the aggregate.
>   The *explicitly initialized* elements of the aggregate are determined as follows: 
>   ... 
>   — If the initializer list is an *initializer-list*, the explicitly initialized elements of the aggregate are the first *n* elements of the aggregate, where *n* is the number of elements in the initializer list.
>   — Otherwise, the initializer list must be `{}`, and there are no explicitly initialized elements.

*[[dcl.init.aggr]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#5)*

> For a non-union aggregate, each element that is not an explicitly initialized element is initialized as follows:  
>   ... 
>   — Otherwise, if the element is not a reference, the element is copy-initialized from an empty initializer list ([dcl.init.list]).

The effect of copy initializing `c` from an empty initializer list is described in

*[[dcl.init.list]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3)*

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows: 
>   ... 
>   — Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and `T` is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.

*[[dcl.init]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#8)*

> To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means: 
>   ... 
>   — if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type with either no default constructor ([class.ctor]) or a default constructor that is user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;

*[[dcl.init]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#7)*

> To *default-initialize* an object of type `T` means: 
>   — If T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated ([over.match.ctor]), and the best one for the initializer () is chosen through overload resolution. The constructor thus selected is called, with an empty argument list, to initialize the object.

*[[over.match.ctor]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.ctor)*

> ... For copy-initialization, the candidate functions are all the converting constructors of that class.

*[[class.conv.ctor]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.ctor#1)*

> A constructor declared without the *function-specifier* `explicit` specifies a conversion from the types of its parameters (if any) to the type of its class. Such a constructor is called a *converting constructor*.

In the example above, `a` has no converting constructors, so overload resolution fails. The (non-normative) example in *[class.conv.ctor]/2* even contains a very similar case

> ```
>   struct Z {
>     explicit Z();
>     explicit Z(int);
>     explicit Z(int, int);
>   };
>
>   Z c = {};                       // error: copy-list-initialization
> ```

---

You can avoid the error by providing a default member initializer for `c`

```
struct b
{
    a c{};  // direct-list-initialization, explicit ctor is OK
};
```

Comment: Does it mean that it's a bug in GCC 5.x and MSVC? GCC 4.9.2 compiles OP's code as well.

Comment: @DanielLangr The current wording that mentions copy initialization was introduced as part of the [change](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/2442418d5c3949a81d540284f8ccec5d0d24ac5f) for designated initializers. If I compare that to N4140 (C++14 draft), the previous wording was *if there is no brace-or-equal initializer,
from an empty initializer list*, which I suppose could be construed as direct list initialization. That could be why older compilers accept it. I can't find a specific reason "copy initialization" was introduced..

Comment: There's also this [paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0280r0.html) that deals with the `explicit` constructor issue by stating the remaining members are initialized by direct-list-initialization, but I can't find anything about what happened to that paper.

Comment: You have "randomly" picked a rule from [over.match.list] without stating why this rule applies. You haven't shown the relevant chain of verbiage from [dcl.init.list] that your previous quote referred to. So the quote is essentially useless. I can't understand: Why is this rule active?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Better?

Comment: @Praetorian thanks. But now there seems a contradiction as your quote says that the overload resolution uses over.match.ctor with an initializer "()", while other parts of your answer still say it uses and it quotes over.match.list.

Comment: over.match.ctor says "For direct-initialization or default-initialization that is not in the context of copy-initialization, the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class of the object being initialized. For copy-initialization, the candidate functions are all the converting constructors of that class. The argument list is the expression-list or assignment-expression of the initializer.". This means that we only consider converting constructors.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Thanks, I think I see what you're pointing me towards. I was trying too hard to reach over.match.list, mainly because it fit the error message, but it seems that [does not apply](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1518). class.conv.ctor itself says no constructor of `a` is viable in this case.