# Use of explicit constructor if the constructor doesn't take any input parameters?

Tags: c++, constructor

I understood 'explicit' concept related to constructors in C++ which will take single parameter as input. But I read on some websites that we need to change the constructor to explicit, irrespective of the number of parameters the constructor will take as input.

Can any one please help me to understand below issues.

1. Why do we need to make a constructor as explicit if it doesn't take any input?
2. What is the use of making a constructor as explicit if it takes more than one parameter and all the parameters are not default?

Comment: Could you cite where did you read that? IMHO it seems wrong. If you want explicit constructor, than you gotta use single parameter.

Comment: There does seem to be some functional differences with an explicit default constructor as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48677746/explicit-default-constructor

Comment: @Vilius `explicit` makes perfect sense for a constructor with multiple arguments if some (or all) of those arguments have default values - in rhat case it is still a "conversion constructor".

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. My initial comment is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do we need to make a constructor as explicit if it doesn't take any input?

That seems incorrect to me. A constructor needs to be explicit if you don't want the constructor to be called automatically.

Say you have:

```
struct Foo 
{
   Foo() {}
   Foo(int) {}
};

void bar(Foo)
{
}
```

Then,

```
bar(1);
```

will work. It is translated as:

```
bar(Foo(1));
```

If there is a default constructor, i.e. one that does not take any arguments, there is nothing to convert from. You may not use:

```
bar();
```

and hope to get it translated as:

```
bar(Foo{});
```

> What is the use of making a constructor as explicit if it takes more than one parameter and all the parameters are not default?

This one has some validity.

If you had:

```
struct Foo 
{
   Foo() {}
   Foo(int, int) {}
};

void bar(Foo)
{
}
```

You may not use

```
bar(10, 20);
```

or

```
bar((10, 20));
```

and hope to have it translated as:

```
bar(Foo(10, 20));
```

However, you may use:

```
bar({10, 20});
```

and it will be translated as:

```
bar(Foo{10, 20});
```

If you want to prevent use of this syntax, `bar({10, 20})`, you may make the constructor `explicit`. IMO, this has less utility. The potential for inadvertently misusing a constructor with one argument is real. The potential for inadvertently misusing a constructor with more than one argument is very small.

Comment: Can you please let me know any practical use of explicit constructor even in case of single parameter?

Comment: @kadina, hop on over to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437241/c-always-use-explicit-constructor and follow the link to http://www.sjbrown.co.uk/2004/05/01/always-use-explicit/.

Comment: @kadina implicit single arg ctor is called conversion ctor; meaning that input and resultant object are somewhat equivalent(eg. complex and real numbers). Consider a vector and its size: does it make sense to init the vector with an assignmentlike syntax?

Comment: The argument for marking a default constructor `explicit` is to improve clarity of code (e.g.: needing to write `bar(foo{})` opposed to writing `bar({})`), just like using a two-valued `enum` instead of a `bool` (e.g.: writing `bar(pin::on)` opposed to `bar(true)`). It might also help catching bugs if the signature of `bar` is ever changed.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement @R Sahu's answer from a different perspective:

The recommendation to use `explicit` for every constructor irrespective of how many arguments it takes can steam from the fact that strictly speaking every C++ constructor should be `explicit` by default and instead we would use `implicit` keyword: [why constructors aren't explicit by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607047/why-constructors-arent-explicit-by-default)

I saw this problem so many times: initially a class has a default constructor. Then after a while it's modified and a parameter is added. It's very easy to forget to add `explicit` in this case.

It's even easier to forget to add `explicit` when you remove a parameter from a two-arguments constructor. Also often your initial `explicit` one-parameter constructor got additional parameters or lost its parameter but `explicit` was left by mistake and compiler doesn't complain about this.

After a while your code starts to look like a christmas tree with many constructors that should be `explicit` but are not and others that are but shouldn't.

I *suppose* it's the reason why the website you mentioned recommends to use `explicit` always.